# Prometheusrule helm release

Tags: helm

Does anyone know if it is possible to create helm release for prometheusrule in such format?
eg.

```
kind: HelmRelease
metadata:
  name: prometheus
  namespace: prometheus
spec:
  releaseName: prometheus
  chart:
    spec:
      chart: prometheus
      version: "15.0.1"
      sourceRef:
        kind: HelmRepository
        name: prometheus
        namespace: flux2-system
  interval: 5m
  values:
    serviceAccounts:
      server:
        name: "amp-iamproxy-ingest-pdtk-cd-service-account"
        annotations:
          eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: "arn:aws:iam::434506272915:role/amp-iamproxy-pdtk-cd-ingest-role"
    alertmanager:
      enabled: true
    nodeExporter:
      enabled: true
    configmapReload:
      alertmanager:
        enabled: true
```